# Next 13 waterfall pattern not functioning

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to trigger loading state whenever request is sent, first I tried to do it on server-side but since data fetching function is dynamic I didn't want to use searchParams for that.

So I decided to use client-side but state does not get updated even through useEffect is triggered .

Here's the code:

> ````
> const [chosenCategory, setChosenCategory] = useState<string>('all')
>   const [featuredProducts, setFeaturedProducts] = useState([])
>   const allProductCategories = [{ href: "all", title: "All" }, ...categories]
>
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     const getFeaturedProducts = async () => {
>       // const data = await getProductsForHomepage('top', '1')
>       // console.log(data.nodes)
>       setFeaturedProducts([1])
>       return
>     }
>
>   
>     getFeaturedProducts()
>
>     console.log(featuredProducts)
>   
>   }, [featuredProducts])
>
>   
>
>  
>
>   if (featuredProducts.length === 0) {
>     return <div>Loading...</div>
>   }
>
>
>     return (
>       <div className=" container flex w-full flex-col gap-8">
>         <div>
>           <h2 className="text-bold-home">{props.title}</h2>
>
>         </div>
>         {/* <Slider
>           elementWidth={100}
>           cards={[productSliderButton]}
>           hideChevorn={false}
>           className="pb-0"
>           title=""
>         /> */}
>         {/*@ts-ignore */}
>       </div>
>     )```
> ````